# Condition that should be true is false (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I have some JS and HTML code. When the user hits the submit button, I want to know which numerical input box (`input type="number"/>`) has text. My conditional statement is: `document.getElementById("fallen").value != 0 || document.getElementById("fallen").value != ""`. This, for some reason, doesn't work. I tried using `document.getElementById("fallen").value == null`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add to your question the whole code fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of any input will always be a string. The statement is working as expected, but you can make one tweak to make it work based on your requirements:

`parseInt(document.getElementById('fallen').value, 10) !== 0`
or
`document.getElementById('fallen').value !== '0'`

Answer (score 2):

something like that ?

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]')
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    inputs.forEach( o => {
        if( o.value ) console.log(o.getAttribute('name'))
    })
})
```

https://codepen.io/Capse/pen/ZxrWwe

Answer (score 1):

see that code , i think this is what you need

```js
function compare(){
  var input =$('input[type="number"]')
  if(!input.val() || input.val()==0){
    console.log ('empty');
  }
  else{
    console.log('the content is '+input.val());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' >
<button onclick=compare()>check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the field using regex like:

If (/^[0-9]{1,}$/.test(myvalue)) console.log('is a number')
else console.log('is not numerical')

Note: Regex test function works also when the myvalue is equal to null.